# React build not working without adding index.html in URL [AWS S3 and Cloudfront deployment]

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am working with React JS application using Hash Routing. On local environment app is working fine.

e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/ should be the URL of application but it is not working and I have to use https://stackoverflow.com/posts/index.html to make it working.

After deployment, I found that it is downloading with name "**download**" empty file instead of serving **index.html** file preset in build file. For running build on server I am using S3 and CloudFront architecture.

Now, I am in a situation where I cannot be able to figure out whether HASH routing is behaving wrong or something wrong with AWS deployment.

Code snippet with React JS

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom/cjs/react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
 <Provider store={store}>
    <HashRouter>
      <App />
    </HashRouter>
  </Provider>

  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Partial package.json content**

```
{
  "name": "loremipsum",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "/loremipsum/"
}
```

Comment: Can you please check if the default root object is set to index.html in your CloudFront distribution? Refer [Specifying a default root object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DefaultRootObject.html)

Comment: @AnkushJain default  root object is already pointed to 
/foldername/index.html

Comment: Why foldername is there? Shouldn’t it be just index.html

Comment: @AnkushJain I just changed the folder name and kept only index.html but still having same problem.

Comment: @VikashDhiman, do you really have to host the files on the sub directory? and not the root directory of the S3 bucket? If yes, are you using webpack or vite?

Answer (score 1):

Are you required to deploy on a subdirectory? If yes, you will have to change the contents of your `package.json` file to force assets to be served relative to `index.html` file.

```json
{
  "name": "loremipsum",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": ".",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "build-prd": "PUBLIC_URL=http://www.foo/relativepath react-scripts build"
    // ...
  }
}
```

With this, we'll be able to move our app's hosted in `http://www.foo` to `http://www.foo/relativepath` or even `https://www.foo/bar1/bar2/` without the need for rebuilds.

You will also have to override the `PUBLIC_URL` to include the domain and subdirectory where you'd like to host your file

Answer (score 1):

Sonetimes the development processing of static content (eg webpack dev server) and the deployed system (eg cloudfront) behave a little differently.

The way to control this in AWS is to use a lambda edge function that controls how paths are interpreted and the default document served. My [blog post](https://authguidance.com/lambda-edge-spa-extensions/) provides a summary, and [this code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/cloudfront-extensions/src/defaultDocument.ts) shows one way of dealing with subpaths:

```js
import {Context} from 'aws-lambda';

const handler = async (event: any, context: Context) => {

    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const requestUri = request.uri.toLowerCase();

    const extensions = [
        '.html',
        '.js',
        '.css',
        '.ico',
    ];

    const knownExtension = extensions.find((ext) => {
        return requestUri.endsWith(`${ext}`);
    });

    if (knownExtension) {
        return request;
    }

    const demoAppBasePath = '/demoapp/';
    if (requestUri.startsWith(demoAppBasePath)) {
        
        request.uri = `${demoAppBasePath}index.html`;
        return request;

    } else {

        request.uri = '/index.html';
        return request;
    };
};

export {handler};
```

Answer (score 1):

Before running npm run build have you tried to edit the package.json file so that the homepage variable has the full URL of your aws hosting site.

"homepage": "yourAWSurlexample.com"

I had trouble with a deployment like this on AWS Amplify and changing the homepage in the package fixed it for me.

After updating the package, create a build and then try to re-push it into AWS.

If this doesn't work AWS Amplify has a really easy setup.  I'm not sure if it would meet your needs but it is really quick to setup and deploy on.